# Error while pressing execute button in moveit with real robot

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I have successfully integrated real robots with moveIt. I can move at my given path with the `plan & execute` button, but if I press the `Plan` button and then it executes that plan. After, when I press the `Execute` button I am obtaining this error, and my robot doesn't move.

Guys any idea where I am doing a mistake?

```
[ERROR] [1617204711.965383782]: 
Invalid Trajectory: start point deviates from current robot state more than 0.01 joint 'joint_a2': expected: -1.5708, current: -1.47654
```

I have checked the things which you maintained but then also I am not able to fix the solution.

When I am doing the plan and execute the first time it is working fine and from the second time I am getting Failed error. I am attaching a screenshot below.

[image: image description]

When I am pressing the plan & execute button I am getting the execution successful!

[image: image description]

Thanks for helping!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375137/error-while-pressing-execute-button-in-moveit-with-real-robot/) by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1622 on 2021-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely, either

- A) your start state is not at your current robot position when you start planning, or
- B) the robot moved after you created the plan.

To set the start state before planning, try selecting the `<current>` option from the `Start State` dropdown menu in the `Planning` tab of the MotionPlanning plugin in Rviz. You can also visualize the start state by looking for the "Query Start" checkbox in the display widget.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-06**:
I have checked these steps and enhanced my question above. Thanks for replying!

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-04-07**:
I don't know how but it started working. Might be Query Start helps